# Java Micrometer @Counted - exception="none" and result="success" for @ExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-micrometer

Quick question regarding Java Micrometer with @Counted and @ExceptionHandler please.

I have a very straightforward @ExceptionHandler:

```
    @ExceptionHandler
    @Counted(value = "MY_EXCEPTION", description = "SOME_DESCRIPTION")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> myCoolExceptionHandler(final RuntimeException runtimeException) {
        System.err.println("an exception!" + runtimeException);
        return Mono.just("bad");
    }
```

I think this combination is quite interesting, as it gives visibility on exception happening. We can build dashboard, alerts, etc, quite cool.

Unfortunately, when I looked at the metric generated, it was something like:

```
# HELP MY_EXCEPTION_total SOME_DESCRIPTION
# TYPE MY_EXCEPTION_total counter
MY_EXCEPTION_total{class="package.MyController",exception="none",method="myCoolExceptionHandler",result="success",} 3.0
```

I am quite puzzled on **exception="none"** and **result="success"**

May I ask how those values got into the metric in the first place?

Also, how to change them into something more meaningful, such as the exception class for instance?

Thank you!

Comment: Guessing: your handler does not throw an exception, therefore the `@Counted` will never record an exception. If you add `throw new RuntimeException("see?")` to your handler's body, you will get a metric with label `exception="RuntimeException"`

Comment: Thank you @knittl. this is exactly what I am trying to ask. My handler does throw the exception. And I see the number correct. In my sample, I had 3 exception thrown, and get the correct value 3.0. And you are also correct, My Handler did throw RuntimeException, this is why, I was excepting ```exception="RuntimeException"```! But got exception="none" and result="success"

Comment: The handler shown in your question does not throw any exception. If it does not throw an exception, then apparently the value of the exception label/tag will be "none". What exactly is the question? The handler itself is successful, the exception was already thrown elsewhere

Comment: Exactly. How to change the value from exception="none" to the exception that has been thrown elsewhere please?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The annotation acts as an interceptor. You can always manually record metrics inside your method with any tags as you like

Comment: "You can always manually record metrics inside your method with any tags as you like" -> agree! But that would result on another metric, I was hoping for a solution that can modify the result of the annotation itself, but indeed, after research, it seems impossible

Comment: Why would it be a new metric? Just reuse the name and tags and it should record values to the same existing metric (and if you manually record the metric, you can remove the annotation; therefore there would be not an additional metric, but simply a "different metric" – which can use the same name of course)

Comment: Yes, my this is what I meant by "another metric" = "different metric". I was hoping I can directly perform some magic on the annotation

Comment: But it doesn't have to be a different metric. Just use the same parameters as you do in your annotation and you will not notice any difference in the resulting metric name/labels and values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotated method itself does not throw an exception and always completes normally. Therefore, the intercepting code installed by the annotation will never record an exception (exception=none) and the outcome will always be good (result=success). Only exceptions thrown from within the annotated method will be recorded as an error outcome.

You can always manually record metrics by injecting the `MetricRegistry` and then registering a metric with the appropriate name and tags.