# Get the count per status in micrometer @Timed annotation

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer

I am using `@Timed` annotation in SpringBoot application to monitor a method. I also want to know the count of response per status.

```
@GetMapping("/status/{productNumber}", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
@Timed(value = "status.productnumber", description = "Timed information retrieveProduct()")
fun retrieveProduct(@PathVariable productNumber: String): ResponseEntity {
```

When I open http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/status.productnumber I see:

```
{
    "name": "status.productnumber",
    "description": "Timed information retrieveProduct()",
    "base_unit": "seconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 3.0
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 0.515840608
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 0.006641343
        }
    ],
    "available_tags": [
        {
            "tag": "exception",
            "values": [
                "None",
                "RuntimeException"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "method",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "uri",
            "values": [
                "/status/{productNumber}"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "outcome",
            "values": [
                "SERVER_ERROR",
                "SUCCESS"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "status",
            "values": [
                "500",
                "200"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the `COUNT` statistic shows the total number of times this endpoint or method is accessed. Can I know the count per status? I want to know how many times 500 status code has occurred

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68394086/java-micrometer-counted-exception-none-and-result-success-for-exceptionh

Comment: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Comment: FYI, if using these metrics in signalfx etc then use the query like `status.productnumber.count` instead of just `status.productnumber` because `status.productnumber` is the parent of the specific metrics like 'count', 'avg' and'max'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the tags this way: `/actuator/metrics/status.productnumber?tag=status:500`, please see the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.endpoint).

A couple of side notes:

- The metrics endpoint is for metrics debugging/troubleshooting purposes, it does not substitute a metrics backend, it should not be used instead of it in prod
- I'm not sure I get what is the purpose of `status.productnumber` by reading its name